# Grails 3, rest-api. How to get associations as objects, not just ids

Tags: json, rest, grails

Building grails app with profile=rest-api. Everything works fine, but associations are shown only as list of ids using JSON as responseFormat. I've tried:

```
static mapping = {
children fetch: 'join'
children lazy: false
}

fetchMode = [children: 'eager']
```

In a controller I'm rendering the JSON response like this:

```
respond Parent.list()
```

Also enabled legacy JSON converter and set:

```
grails.converters.json.default.deep = true
```

So how in earth could I get the children as JSON objects to the response? I need global solution for the app.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than making the association eager by default it is better to use a join query:

```
respond Parent.list(fetch:[children:'join'])
```

Comment: Well, that's "of course" possible, but I would nice to define it "globally" in one place, so no need to add all the needed associations in every db search. I resolved this now by not using respond, but render Object as JSON. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Grails 2.4, but the solution we use is the [Grails Marshallers plugin](https://github.com/pedjak/grails-marshallers).

I can't find any documentation about supporting Grails 3, but it's just a wrapper around existing Grail's methods (`JSON.registerObjectMarshaller()`), so in essence it should work.

```
class Parent {

    ...

    static marshalling = {
        json {
            deep 'children'
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you were adverse to installing a plugin for this specific instance, then you could always use BootStrap.groovy to register your class:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Parent) { p ->
    return [
        p.id
        ...
        children: p.children.collect{ c ->
            [
                id: c.id,
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```